# Binomial distrubution probability

Tags: probability

Hi so the question and solution is

```
A random sample of 5 employees who requested sick leave on a given day has been
selected. What is the probability that 3 or more have the common cold? (5 marks)
Solution: 
X ∼ B in(5, 0.6)
P(X ≥ 3) = 1−P(X ≤ 2) = 1−P2
(1−0.6)(5−k) = 1−(0.01024+0.07680+0.23040) = 0.68256
```

But using the formula i got 1-((.4^4) + 0.6(0.4)^4 + 0.36(0.4)^3) = 1-(0.1024 + 0.01536 + 0.02304) = 0.95

Am I inputting it wrong?

Comment: $P(x\le 2)=q^5+\binom51 pq^4+\binom52 p^2q^3$. $p=0.6=1-q$. You missed the binomial terms.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have .4^4 but it should be .4^5. This corresponds to the case that all 5 of them do not have it. The exponents of each term should add to 5 so we can also think of this term as (.6)^0(.4)^5 and 0+5=5 so it's good.